# When I'm running my code, it shows error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, exception

I'm using opencv v2.4.13 to capture image and also open image file. But when I'm running it shows error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core
at com.ismo.First.<clinit>(First.java:33)
```

This is the code that throws the error:

```
public class First {

static ImgShow imgShowOrigin = new ImgShow("WELCOME");
static String srcPath = "C:/Users/JAFFAR/Pictures/Testing";

static {
    // Load Opencv native library
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Start app...");
    openImage();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}


public static void openImage() {
    Mat m = Highgui.imread(srcPath + "img1.jpg");
    Size imgSize = m.size();
    Imgproc.resize(m, m, new Size(500, imgSize.height * 500 / imgSize.width), 1.0, 1.0, INTER_CUBIC);
    imgShowOrigin.show(m);
}
}
```

Comment: Create a minimal example instead of pasting the whole class in so that one can just see the error and any relevant methods so that readers can focus on that particular tiny piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError occurs when you are trying to access a class that is not in your classpath. So you need to make sure that you have OpenCV library in your classpath. You can get it from OpenCV  [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv/3.2.0-0) page.